# Compser proxy access failes

Tags: debugging, proxy, composer-php

I want to use composer, but the connection fails.
I am using Windows 7 64bit with a company proxy. I already tested to set the environment variable HTTP_PROXY but that did not solve the problem.
If Iy type `composer diag` with HTTP_PROXY set as environment variable I will get:

```
checking http connectivity: FAIL
...
failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy
Checking HTTP proxy: FAIL
```

Without HTTP_PROXY environment variable:

```
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: FAIL
You are not running the latest version
```

What can I do to fix the problem?

I have to use the composer with a proxy-server!

Comment: does nobody know a solution?